# Looking for different bad words in RRS feed, stuck on variable list and if any

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple python script to check bad words in a RSS feed. The feed itself works just fine, also this copypaste works for one bad word but I have bad time checking multiple words.

I have tried making variable badword a list, something like:

```
badword = ["badword", "badderword"]
```

but I get

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list.

I have also tried to use 'if any' but I'm afraid I didn't do that one properly either.

```
feed = "emulating rss feed test ok badword"
badword = "bad"

print("Feed:  " + feed)
print("Bad word: " + str(badword))

if badword not in feed:
    print("Not bad")
else:
    print("Is bad")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` for checking whether any of those bad words are in the feed:

```
>>> feed = "emulating rss feed test ok badword"
>>> badword = ["badword", "badderword"]
>>> any(bw in feed for bw in badword)
True
```

But this may fail if a bad word is part of a non-bad word:

```
>>> feed = "emulating rss feed test ok notreallyabadword"
>>> any(bw in feed for bw in badword)
True
```

Instead, I'd suggest using a regex, joining the bad words with `|` and delimiting them with a word boundary character `\b`. This will also work with punctuation.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = r"\b" + "|".join(badword) + r"\b"
>>> re.search(p, feed) is not None
False
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This works fine, and just now I have realized why I failed with 'any' earlier. 
I'm going for 'any' since the RSS feed is in Finnish, and the way we twist our words it's better if it checks if a badword is in non-badword.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to a list and then compare lists:

```
>>> feed = "emulating rss feed test ok badword"
>>> feedlist = feed.split()
>>> feedlist
['emulating', 'rss', 'feed', 'test', 'ok', 'badword']
>>>
>>>
>>> badwords = ['bad','badword']
>>>
>>>
>>> [item for item in feedlist if item in badwords]
['badword']
>>>
```

Comment: This might fail if a badword is immediately followed by punctuation.